# Notepad++ N text lines separated by blank lines?

Tags: regex, notepad++, editing

I searched a bit, but didn't find a solution for this specific situation. I need to combine groups of non-blank lines into single lines, while preserving the blank lines. For example, the input:

```
Hi, My name is
Max 

What are you
doing
Right now?

Hi

Hello
World
```

**should be output as:**

```
Hi, My name is Max

What are you doing Right now?

Hi

Hello World
```

Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Comment: And what is the problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing

```
(?<![\n\r])[\n\r](?![\n\r])
```

With **a space**, **[as demonstrated here](https://regex101.com/r/kG0uE1/6)**

## Explanation -

`(?<![\n\r])` is a negative look-behind which tells the regex that anything to be matched must not be preceded by a newline or by a carriage return (just take it as a newline)
`[\n\r]` is the newline or carriage return which is matched (and later replaced with a space)
`(?![\n\r])` is a negative look-ahead that tells the regex that any newline to be matched should not be followed by another newline or carriage return.

In essence, this replaces the blank, new lines which are not followed by another newline - with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too,

```
(?m)(?!^\s*$)(^[^\n]*)\n(?!^\s*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/100),,, in which matches all lines which are not empty and not followed by `empty line` and remove all matched `newline character` (`\n`).

But, in `notepad++`, you must consider `carrige return(\r)` with newline(`\n`). Thus,

```
(?m)(?!^\s*$)(^[^\n]*)\r\n(?!^\s*$)
```